# Fourier transform of $\exp(-t^2)$ using contour integration.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am calculating the Fourier transform of $\exp(-t^2)$ using contour integration.

I am left with the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(i\omega t)\exp(-t^2)$.

Usually I would now use the residue theorem, but I cannot find the singularities.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Complete the square and use the Cauchy integral theorem to shift the interval of integration.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you elaborate?

Comment: @rbm Notice $\exp(a)\exp(b) = \exp(a+b)$, then complete the square and proceed as Dainel pointed out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can write

$$\exp (i\omega t)\exp(-t^2) = \exp\left(-(t-i\omega/2)^2\right)\exp\left((i\omega/2)^2\right).$$

The factor $\exp (-\omega^2/4)$ can be pulled out of the integral, and we are left with

$$\int_{-\infty + i0}^{+\infty+i0} \exp \left(-(z-i\omega/2)^2\right)\,dz.$$

Using the Cauchy integral theorem, we can shift the integration to

$$\int_{-\infty + i\omega/2}^{+\infty+i\omega/2}\exp \left(-(z-i\omega/2)^2\right)\,dz,$$

and parametrising as $z = t + i\omega/2$, that becomes

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-t^2)\,dt.$$

The shift of the contour of integration is justified by applying the Cauchy integral theorem to a rectangle with vertices $-R,\, R,\, R+i\omega/2,\, -R+i\omega/2$ and taking the limit $R\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thank you. Could this also have been done using contour integration?

Comment: Since the integrand is an entire function, the integral over all closed contours is zero. We used that to shift the integral, so in some sense, we used contour integration. If you want something like expressing the integral as the sum of residues enclosed by a contour, I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Can you show mathematically why the integration through the other  two sides of the rectangle (−R,R,R+iω/2,−R+iω/2 ) is zero?

Comment: @ecook The integral isn't zero (generally; for some $R$ it might happen to be zero), but the limit as $R \to +\infty$ of the integrals over the vertical segments is zero. On these segments, $z = \pm R + iy$, with $\lvert y\rvert \leqslant \lvert\omega/2\rvert$, thus $$\lvert \exp(-z^2)\rvert = \exp(\operatorname{Re} (-z^2)) = \exp(y^2 - R^2) \leqslant e^{\omega^2/4}\cdot e^{-R^2}\,.$$ This tends to $0$ very fast.